# I want to find an input element closest a span when I click the span, can you help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find an input element closest a span when i click the span

HTML

```
<div>
   <span class="text"></span>
   <input type="text" name="an_element_name">
</div>
<div>
   <span class="text"></span>
   <input type="text" name="an_element_name">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.text').click(function(e){
   let text = $(e.target),
       input = text.closest('input[name=an_element_name]').find('input[name=an_element_name]');

   input.val('some value');
});
```

but, I'm still can't set a value of the input. Can you help me ?

Comment: `let input = this.nextElementSibling`

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center -> Traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) incorrectly, you should use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead.

> **next():** Get the immediately *following sibling* of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You can achieve it in this simple way

```js
$('.text').click(function(e){
   let text = $(e.target),
       input = text.next('input[name=an_element_name]');

   input.val('some value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">Click me</span>
<input type="text" name="an_element_name">
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should consider leaving a note for the OP to understand what was wrong. `You can achieve it in this simple way` don't really give the OP a good understand about what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text.next('input[name=an_element_name]');` since the `.closest()` is looking for an ancestor of your span, not siblings.

- `.closest()` = Goes up the html tree and search for the element.
- `.next()` = Searches for an element after the current element.
- `.find()` = Searches for children of the given element.

**Demo**

```js
$('.text').click(function(e){
   let text = $(e.target),
       input = text.next('input[name=an_element_name]');
   input.val('some value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">click</span>
<input type="text" name="an_element_name">
```